# Python fnmatch with parentheses and commas

Tags: python, glob

I'm doing a walk through a dir, and trying to collect files which contain the string `(0, 0, 0)` using `fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'*(0, 0, 0)*')`. It looks like the parentheses and commas are throwing it off, and matching to strings like `(0, 1, 1)`, which I don't want.

The relevant snippet is:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_dir):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, file)
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename,'*\(0, 0, 0\)*'):
            # do stuff
```

and the dirs contain files such as:

```
\c_(0, 0, 0)\data.txt
\c_(0, 05, 05)\data.txt
\c_(0, 05, 1)\data.txt
\c_(0, 1, 0)\data.txt
```

My understanding is that escaping the parentheses should fix it, but no luck there. What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide an **[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files_list=[]

for filename in os.listdir(r'DirPath'):
    if filename.count('(0, 0, 0)'):
        files_list.append(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape spaces also.

try this : `*\(0,\ 0,\ 0\)*`